# sendKeysToElement executing but keys not being passed in selenium

Tags: r, selenium, flexbox, sendkeys

I am having difficulty changing the value of what appears to be a dropdown box (but I don't think is) on [this page](https://www.itftennis.com/en/tournament/m15-monastir/tun/2021/m-itf-tun-52a-2021/draws-and-results/) when interacting it with Selenium in R.

I don't think it's a dropdown because there are not separate xpaths for the 2 options ("Singles" and "Doubles"). When toggling between the options I can see that the only thing that differs is the content for the final node.

I have therefore tried a different method to (1) select the "dropdown", (2) type the option I want and then (3) click enter. However, this is not working because neither text nor keystrokes are being passed to the webpage.

```
library('RSelenium')
library('rvest')
library('tidyverse')
library('seleniumPipes') 

single.double.elem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*[@class=' css-1hwfws3']") #find element
single.double.elem$clickElement() #click it
single.double.elem$sendKeysToElement(list("Doubles")) #attempt to type into box. This executes but the text is not passed to the box
single.double.elem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "down_arrow")) #alternatively, attempt to go down to select Doubles option. This executes but nothing happens
```

What am I doing wrong here? I note that some elements have "flex" next to them - could this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the drop down button is visible on the screen and this should work as it did for me:

```
# to click on Doubles dropdown
dropdownButton <- remdr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//span[@class='icon']")$clickElement()
selectButton <- remdr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//div[text()='Doubles']")$clickElement()

# to click on Singles dropdown
dropdownButton <- remdr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//span[@class='icon']")$clickElement()
selectButton <- remdr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//div[text()='Singles']")$clickElement()
```